# How is the probability defined when there are many sets?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider a domain set $X$, a label set $Y = \{0,1\}$ and a function $h : X \to Y$. What is meant by $\mathbb{P}(h(x)=1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(h(x^*)=1)$ where $x^*$ is a particular/chosen element in $X$?

1. Either $\mathbb{P}(h(x)=1) = \mathbb{P}(\{(x,y,h) \in (X, Y, Y) : h(x) = 1\})$ or $\mathbb{P}(\{x \in X : h(x) = 1\})$ holds and I don't know which one does. **Either way, does it matter (in general)?**
2. I think $\mathbb{P}(h(x^*)=1) = \mathbb{P}(\{y \in Y : (h(x^*) = y) \land \ (y = 1) \}) = 1/2$ or $\mathbb{P}(\{(x,y) \in (X,Y) : (h(x^*) = y) \land (x = x^*) \ \land \ (y=1)$. I don't know which one it is though.

Can I get a general way to look at probabilities? I don't understand if $\mathbb{P}$ defined every time or it depends on the sets written as arguments.

Comment: Where have you seen this notation? Maybe add a link to you reference document.

Comment: @EtienneBfx Nowhere. I need to calculate $\mathbb{P}(h(x) \neq 1), \mathbb{P}(h(x)=1)$ and $\mathbb{P}(h(t)=1)$ (for a given $t \in \text{X}$). I just can't figure out which two sets I should take the ratio of, in case case.

Comment: So I don't understand, you created your own notation and at the same time you ask what is meant by that?

Comment: Typically, one is given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$ and would consider the random variable $x\colon\Omega\to X$. Then $\mathbb{P}(h(x)=1)$ means $\mathbb{P}(\lbrace\omega\in\Omega\ \colon \ h(x(\omega))=1\rbrace)$.

Comment: @EtienneBfx I think the that the question arose precisely due to the fact that there are difficulties with the formalization of intuitive ideas

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you suppose that there is a random variable on some probability space. You use the term $x$ for random variable, but it's more common to use a term $x$ for values of random variables and a term $X$ for random variables.

Suppose that $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is a probability space and $X$ is a random varible.  By definition $P(X \in D)$ is $P( \{ \omega: X(\omega) \in D \})$.

We have
$\mathbb{P}(h(X)=1) = P(\{ \omega: h(X(\omega)) = 1 \})$.

So, $\mathbb{P}(h(X)=1) = P(X \in \{x: h(x) = 1\} ) = P(\{ \omega: X(\omega) \in \{x: h(x) = 1\}  \})$ and it's equal to   $\mathbb{P}( (X,h(X)) \in \{(x,y): h(x) = 1\})$.

Further, $\mathbb{P}(h(x^*)=1)$ is a bit strange, because $h(x^*)$ is not a random variable. It's something like $\mathbb{P}(\sin(\frac{\pi}2)=1)$. So, if $h(x^*)=1$ then $\mathbb{P}(h(x^*)=1) = 1$ and otherwise $\mathbb{P}(h(x^*)=1) = 0$.